# How to change glossaries alttree: no bold font for second level

Tags: formatting, glossaries

How can I modify the glossaries e.g. `alttree` style to not use bold fonts for the entries in second level. First level should remain bold.

I'd like to do it like

```
\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
\glossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand{\glsgroupskip}{}% make nothing happen between groups
}
```

but I do not know the command to "renew"

P.S.: Using the `longragged` style would fit even better. In that case I'd like to change the identication of the first column and make first level entries bold.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into [glossaries.pdf](http://texdoc.net/pkg/glossaries.pdf) or `glossary-longragged.sty` you will find the following definition of the glossary style `longragged`:

```
\newglossarystyle{longragged}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{l>{\raggedright}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5%
    \tabularnewline}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
     &
     \glssubentryitem{##2}%
     \glstarget{##2}{\strut}##4\glspostdescription\space ##6%
    \tabularnewline}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else & \tabularnewline\fi}%
}
```

Now what you need to do is change the definitions that you want differently in your style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries,glossary-longragged}
\usepackage{tabu}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{test}{name={test},description={some description text}}
\newglossaryentry{test2}{name={another test},description={some description text}}
\newglossaryentry{test3}{name={a third test},description={some description text}}
\newglossaryentry{parent}{name={parent},description={\nopostdesc}}
\newglossaryentry{child1}
  {name={child 1},description={some description text},parent={parent}}
\newglossaryentry{child2}
  {name={child 2},description={some description text},parent={parent}}

\newglossarystyle{mylongragged}{%
  \glossarystyle{longragged}
  % with ``I'd like to change the identication of the first column''
  % you presumably mean you want the table to fill the line width?
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {X[2l]X[8p]}}%
     {\end{longtabu}}%
  % renew the entry field to make the entries bold by adding \bfseries:
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \bfseries\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5%
    \tabularnewline}%
  % renew the entry field for sub entries; make them non bold indented
  % versions of the main entries:
  \renewcommand*{\glossarysubentryfield}[6]{%
    \quad\glssubentryitem{##2}\glstarget{##2}{##3} & ##4\glspostdescription\space ##6%
    \tabularnewline}%
}
\glossarystyle{mylongragged}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind giving an example with two levels? That is what I am searching for. Thanks anyway for the solution given above

Comment: @louiscypher see the edit. Does that help you?